# How can I stop the numberpad from jumping to the next textview?

Tags: android

I have the layout shown below.  Typically the user will just fill in the first box (etItemQty) and then can save the data - how do I stop the keypad from allowing the user to go to the 'next' edit box (which is etItemPrice).  I only want the user to be able to click on etItemPrice specifically, if they want to edit it.  In other languages I don't give it a tabStop position - is this possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lbProducts"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/sm_lbProduct"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinProducts"
                            android:layout_width="210dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>





                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="321dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lbProductQty"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/sm_lbProductQty"
                             android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etProductQty"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:width="50px"
                            android:inputType="phone" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                        <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lbPrice"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/sm_lbProductPrice"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etProductPriceExGST"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                            android:width="100px"

                            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:padding="5dp">

                         <Button
                            android:id="@+id/cmdAddItem"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/sm_cmdAddProduct" />

                    </LinearLayout>


     <LinearLayout  
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">



        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewOrders"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="141dp" >

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>









</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    etItemQty.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
        {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(etItemQty.getWindowToken(), 0);

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: does this just close it only when the user presses the enter key - or does it close it before arriving at the textview?

Comment: It will close when user press the enter...how you will know that user complete the input?

Comment: What would be perfect is if the focus never goes to the textview in the first place, i.e that 'next' does not appear on the softkeyboard.

Comment: how you can remove `next` in soft keyboard?

Comment: Is there a textview setting that stops it from appearing on the 'edit path' that the softkeyboard follows?